# link iPhone control app to main iPad app

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod-touch

Does anyone know what might be the best way to go about doing this? My CS research prof. suggested that Bluetooth might be the best way to go.

I am working on a music app for iPad and want to make a separate app on an iPhone/iPod touch to act as a remote control for the main app. Just sending a few button/slider/etc messages to a few IBActions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right approach.

Refer to the [CoreBluetooth Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011295) for all the necessary information.
There is also [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TemperatureSensor/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012194).

Comment: Hi there, just a quick followup for clarification: The documentation says that this sample code requires an iPhone 4S, which I have, but is a bit ambiguous - does it actually require two iPhone 4S's? I am trying to get an iPhone 4S and iPad 2 connected at the moment. Thanks

Comment: I should add that I have built the sample application to both devices and neither device can see the other through any combination of having the sample app launched and having the other device on the Bluetooth Settings page Discoverable and Searching...

Comment: I think I may have found my own answer here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy#Other_examples_of_compatible_devices
Only the iPad 3rd generation would support what I am trying to do (I guess the documentation for that sample code hasn't been updated to mention that).